# How do i receive the most recent data in Real-Time Database using the Node.js in the fulfillment section?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase-realtime-database, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to retrieve the most recent data entry in my Real-Time database.

I've tried using my own codes where I tried to take a snapshot of the child, but it seems like its not working.

This is what I've tried :

```
  function checkMathAnswer(agent){
      let ref = admin.database().ref('MathAnswer');

      return ref.orderByChild("Answer").once('value').then((snapshot) => {

        const value = childSnapshot.child('Answer').val();

        agent.add(value);

      });
  }
```

I expect the result to be "146" only (as seen in my firebase screenshot).

[This is my Firebase Real-Time Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIna0.jpg)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is make a new key of `"time_of_entry"` in your database and sort according to that the most recent entry will be at last. As it will be sorted in ascending order.

Comment: i've created a new key where when a new data is stored, both the "Answer" and "TimeStamp" will be saved. But what is the code to retrieve the "Answer" of the latest "TimeStamp" ?